# Create custom filter predicate from Maps lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to create a dynamic predicate to filter out the list of employees based on the given filter map. I have this example of a filter like this :

```java
Map<String, String> filters = new HashMap<String, String>();
filters.put("firstName", "John");
filters.put("country", "US");
//can add new filters in the future
```

I know the traditional way is to filter it like this :

```
employees.stream().filter(e -> e.getFirstName().equals("John") && e.getCountry().equals("US")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However I want to make the predicate in the filter method dynamic based on the filter maps that was pass. I tried experimenting but still no luck. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You want the filter to be dynamic based on what?

Comment: Based on the filter map coming from the front end. I have example above.

Comment: Does it have to be a `Map<String, String>`? This way you are pretty much forced to use reflection. Much easier to get `firstName` with a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution without changing `Employee` you can use reflection:

```
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate; 

public class PredicateBuilder {

    private Predicate<Employee> predicate;
    private boolean isError = false;

    public PredicateBuilder(Map<String, String> filters ) {
        buildPredicate(filters);
    }

    private  void buildPredicate(Map<String, String> filters) {

        predicate = null;
        for(String propertyName : filters.keySet()){

            Method method = methodByName(convertPropertyNameToGetterName(propertyName));
            if(method == null ) {
                continue;
            }
            String value = filters.get(propertyName);
            Predicate<Employee> p = makePredicate(method, value);
            if(p == null ) {
                continue;
            }
            predicate = predicate == null ? p : predicate.and(p);
        }
    }

    private String convertPropertyNameToGetterName(String propertyName) {
        propertyName = propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1);
        return "get"+propertyName;
    }

    private Predicate<Employee> makePredicate(Method method, String value){
        isError = false;

        Predicate<Employee> p = e -> {
            try {
                return method.invoke(e).equals(value);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                isError = true;
                return false;
            }
        };
        return isError ? null : p;
    }

    private static Method methodByName(String name){
        try {
            return Employee.class.getDeclaredMethod(name);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Predicate<Employee> getPredicate() {
        return predicate;
    }
}
```

Usage example: `Predicate<Employee> p = new PredicateBuilder(filters).getPredicate();`

If you need a solution without changing `Employee` and without using reflection, you'll end up with a rigid and not easy to maintain solution:

```
static Predicate<Employee> buildPredicate(Map<String, String> filters) {
        Predicate<Employee> predicate = null;

        for(String key : filters.keySet()){
             Predicate<Employee> p = null;
            switch (key) {
                case "firstName":
                    p = e -> e.getFirstName().equals(filters.get(key));
                    break;

                case "country":
                    p =  e-> e.getCountry().equals(filters.get(key));
                    break;
            }
            if(p == null ) {
                continue;
            }
            predicate = predicate == null ? p : predicate.and(p);
        }
        return predicate;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not recommend using `Map`. It is much better to create a separate class with required fields, let's call it `EmployeeFilter`.

Then your method should accept this filter and transform it to `Predicate<Employee>` by checking all fields for `null` (it means not filter by this field). If the field is not `null`, then add the given check to the **predicate chain**.

```java
public class Main {

    static class EmployeeFilter {

        private String firstName;
        private String country;

    }

    static class Employee {

        private String firstName;
        private String country;

    }


    public static List<Employee> getEmployeesByFilter(List<Employee> employees, EmployeeFilter filter) {
        return employees.stream()
                        .filter(createPredicate(filter))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Predicate<Employee> createPredicate(EmployeeFilter filter) {
        Predicate<Employee> predicate = employee -> true;

        if (filter.firstName != null)
            predicate = predicate.and(employee -> filter.firstName.equals(employee.firstName));
        if (filter.country != null)
            predicate = predicate.and(employee -> filter.country.equals(employee.country));

        return predicate;
    }

}
```